# how to write junit for existing application what should be taken care for that

Tags: unit-testing, junit

i am confuse about how to implement **Junit** in my existing application.i am not getting from where i should start.

i read many article and tutorials from internet about **Junit** most of them shows syntax and basic example with 1 java class and i have read that **junit** is only use with stand-alone java class.but my question is my web application contains many classes, methods and **JDBC** query then how and what should i test in that using **Junit**.

Comment: The problem you will probably face is that if you didn't design the application with testing in mind, it will probably not be designed to make testing easy. That said, TrueDub's answer is fairly accurate. Learn about mocking and the start by testing one class (start with something that is not a Controller or DAO). Then go to the next class.

Comment: Part of the confusion is that unit testing, especially in JUnit, works for testing individual things, without context. However, when you are doing integration testing, context is critical. You might want to consider TestNG instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up about unit testing in general, and mocking in particular. What you're trying to achieve is to test each class in a standalone fashion, by providing mock versions of its dependencies, where you control the output of each method call.